# Any local task queue(maybe disk queue or mem queue?) for producer and worker(python)?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, task

I have used a lot of distribute task package, like `celery`, `python-rq`, they all depend on a external service such as `redis`, `rabbit-mq` and so on.

But, usually I don't need a `queue service`, in another word , don't want to install `redis` or other non-python service on my vps.(also to simplify the environment)

I should say that it is good to split `producer` and `worker` to different process(two code file). Using `multiprocessing.Queue` need put all stuff into one file, and need write a lot of additional code to catch `ctrl+c` to handler the `exit` and save current enqueued tasks. This would not happened by using `celery`, `python-rq`, though stop workers and producers, tasks still saved in the queue.

I'd like to use a local queue(can work just by `pip install xxx`), such as a disk queue.
After some searching, only find [queuelib(Collection of persistent (disk-based) queues)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/queuelib), but sadly it don't support access from to multi processes.

Answer (score 1):

Check [`Luigi`](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/index.html) package.
It allows definition of multiple tasks with all the dependencies and then request it to run with particular parameters.

It runs so called scheduler, which can be local one or "production" one in form of web service.

Luigi has a concept of finished tasks, being marked by presence of some sort of target. The target can be a file on local filesystem, on AWS S3 etc. Once the target exists, the task is considered to be completed. Luigi takes care of creating the target files atomically, this means, the file is created first in some temporary location and moved to final one after it is really completed. This prevents having half-finished targets.

If you stop the processing in the middle, next start will check for existence of completed targets and start processing only those, which are not completed yet.

There is no extra service to install, the command sets up the local or "production" scheduler on its own, if not existing yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think [nq](https://github.com/leahneukirchen/nq) may be a good solution for your case.

> These small utilities allow creating very lightweight job queue systems which require no setup, maintenance, supervision, or any long-running processes.

You can use command interface to manage background task and the only dependency is file system.